# Android - how to get the layout id from a view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Hello fellow developers!

i'll keep this as simple and short as I can,
I have a fragment, and in my onCreateView I am sometimes giving it different layouts depend on my status.

is there any way of knowing on which layout I am?

code below:

my onCreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view;

    if (programState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_program_on, container, false);
    } else {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }

    findViews(view);
    setupViews();
    return view;
}
```

basically, my "findViews" method gets that View, and I was wondering if there's a way to know which layout i am on with a switch statement for example or something like that.. like this :

```
private void findViews(View mainView) {

    switch(mainView) {
        case R.layout.fragment_home:
            //do work
            break;
        case R.layout.fragment_home_program_on:
            //do work
            break;
    }
}
```

I am trying to do something like that with no success.. all i get is errors and such, is there a way to do that?

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I did search and didn't found anything.. don't down vote for no reason please!
and if it was indeed asked, please share a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any way of knowing on which layout I am?

Sure. Check `programState`. You are already doing that to determine which layout to load, so use that to determine which layout you loaded.

> I was wondering if there's a way to know which layout i am

Use `if (programState)`, the same way you did in `onCreateView()`.

Beyond that, a widget has no idea what layout resource it came from. So, *somewhere*, you need to track that information yourself, and you seem to be doing so already in `programState`.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for answering, well, but i wish to add more layout options.. not just two.. i'll improvise with an enum or something i guess, ty.

Comment: @JozeRi: "i wish to add more layout options.. not just two" -- change `programState` to something else (such as your suggested enum), but then still use `programState` for both your inflation decision and your "hey, which layout did I inflate?" decision later on.

Answer (score 0):

try `mainView.getId()` in switch. I think that's what you need

Comment: Hi buddy, thanks for trying to help!, i have tried that already, no go..
also tried mainView.getRootView().getId();

Comment: Well, that's not really how fragments should work, check this tutorial, it's pretty good: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html

Comment: View.getId() returns the `android:id` associated with the view on which it is called.  Unless each for the different layouts happens to assign a different id to it's root view (woo... now there's a hack!), this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to something like this:

```
private void findViews(View mainView) {
int viewId = mainView.getId();
    switch(viewId) {
        case R.id.firstViewId:
            //do work
            break;
        case R.id.secondViewId:
            //do work
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have various Views and you need to differentiate them - try adding tags to them.

1 - If you are going to have more then one tag type - create keys for them. 
And use `mainView.setTag(TAG_TYPE_ID_1, 10011)` (many tags for a view) rather than `mainView.setTag(10011)` (only one tag for a view). 
In this case TAG_TYPE_ID_1 may be your constant field. It **must** be initialized with id of some Resource. For example `public static final int TAG_TYPE_ID_1 = R.layout.my_frame_layout;`
Also consider placing `int viewId = (int) mainView.getTag()` into try/catch because you can get ClassCastException if you will put there a `String` for example but will try to get `int`.

But for this example we assume you don't need lots of tags and you know that you have only `int` as a tag.

2 - Set tag into the view in onCreateview() method in your fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {    View view;
    if (programState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_program_on, container, false);
        view.setTag(1011);
    } else {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        view.setTag(1012);
    }

    findViews(view);
    setupViews();
    return view;
}
```

3 - Then read the tag value in your view and decide what to do

```
private void findViews(View mainView) {

if(mainView.getTag() == null)
    return;


switch((int) mainView.getTag()) {
    case 1011:
        //do work
        break;
    case 1012:
        //do work
        break;
}
```

}

NOTE: don't forget that here `switch((int) mainView.getTag())` you can get ClassCastException or NullPointerException if tag will be different type or null

Also `int` codes like `1011`, `1012` etc. is better to store as a constant fields